# Apache rewrite rules don't work after excluding directory from authentication

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I want the content of a directory "dir" protected, but if the user accesses the directory itself, I want a PHP file from the parent directory served instead.
This works with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    LogLevel debug
    
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName example.com
    
    <Directory /var/www/html>
    
        SetEnvIf Request_URI "dir/$" allow  
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from env=allow
        Satisfy any
    
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule dir index.php?id=dir [QSA,L]    
    </Directory>
    
    <Directory /var/www/html/dir>
        Require user valid-user 
        AuthName "Restricted"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        
        #RewriteEngine on
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I access "example.com/dir" the content of index.php is displayed, when I access "example.com/dir/file.html" I have to authenticate first. Everything is as wanted.

But when I now try to create RewriteRules for other files, I quits working. When I just uncomment the line "#RewriteEngine on" at the end, I get a 404 not found when I try to access "example.com/dir".

Why does this happen? I don't need other rewrite rules for "dir" itself but for some files within the directory.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I now try to create RewriteRules for other files, I quits working. When I just uncomment the line "#RewriteEngine on" at the end, I get a 404 not found when I try to access "example.com/dir".

Because mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default in a *directory* context. When you set `RewriteEngine On` in the `<Directory /var/www/html/dir>` container it completely overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent (they do not even run).

To resolve this as you have written it then you would need to enable mod_rewrite inheritance. However, mod_rewrite directives are essentially copied in-place when they are "inherited", and the directive you posted would not work if it was included in the `<Directory /var/www/html/dir>` container, since the regex `dir` would not match.

> ```
> RewriteRule dir index.php?id=dir [QSA,L]
> ```

Note that this doesn't just rewrite requests to the directory itself, it rewrites any request that simply contains `dir`.

To make this "inheritable" (ie. not dependent on the current directory), change it to read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(dir)/?$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?id=%1 [QSA,L]
```

And in the `<Directory /var/www/html/dir>` container, enable mod_rewrite inheritance. Either:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Parent directives are copied AFTER directives in the current scope
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Or

```
# Parent directives are copied BEFORE directives in the current scope
RewriteOptions InheritBefore
```

(Apache 2.2 only have the `inherit` option.)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately adding RewriteOptions does not change anything. Just uncommenting "RewriteEngine on" or adding any of the two "RewriteOptions" results in a 404 message for "example.com/dir". My .config file above should be a complete example to reproduce (Apache 2.4.41 Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: I forgot the log message: It is "AH00129: Attempt to serve directory: /var/www/html/dir/"